# How does Google Analytics export PDFs?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Does anyone know how Google Analytics exports their PDFs? They don't seem to make a call back to their server when you click to export, which leads me to believe that it's done client side. But honestly I have no idea. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do call the server : https://www.google.com/analytics/web/exportReport?ef=PDF
(arguments in POST)

Use the network tab of Chrome's console to see the request.

So, as we don't have Google code you can't get more information about how they do it (but there are many ways to generate PDF server side, especially in java which is the most used language at Google).